# Computating of Last Active Date for Each User Using Incremental Model in Snowflake SQL and dbt

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, dbt

I am creating a table via an incremental model using dbt and Snowflake SQL.

The table has three columns: user_id, date, and active.

I want to calculate the last active date for each user based on the latest date they were active.

Due to the size of the data, I only want to look at the last record for each user to keep producing the last active date for each user in an incremental model.

Here is an example image of the table I am working with:

[image]

I tried using sliding windows and the MAX function, but it may not capture the last active date for each user since it is not an incremental approach (requires looking at unbounded preceding rows).

```sql
,case when active = 1 then daily_date else null end active_dt

,max(active_dt) over (partition by user_id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as last_active_dt
```

I also tried using the LAG function to push the last active date forward, but it may result in a blank value if a user was not active on the previous record.

```sql
,case when active = 1 then daily_date else null end active_dt

 ,coalesce(
        case when active = 1 then daily_date end
        ,lag(active_dt) ignore nulls over (partition by user_id order by date)
            ) as last_active_dt
```

The other approach I took was to get the last active date using a qualify, and while this may work for incremental daily loads, it would not function properly for a full refresh:

```
,last_active_dt_cte as (
    select
    user_id
    ,active_dt as last_active_dt

    from {{ ref('daily_user_activity_table') }}
    where 1 = 1
    and date >= '2022-11-01'

 
    --get last active date relative to last date in this table
    and date <= (select max(date) from {{ this }})
  
    qualify row_number() over (partition by user_id order by active_dt desc) = 1

)
```

How can I efficiently calculate the last active date for each user in a way that accommodates both incremental updates and full refreshes?

Comment: Re- *I also tried using the LAG function to push the last active date forward, but it may result in a blank value if a user was not active on the previous record* : What would you expect instead of blank then?

Comment: Try ``max(case when active = 1 then daily_date else null end) over (partition by user_id order by daily_date desc) as last_active_dt``

Comment: Would it make sense to keep the last active date in a separate "summary" table? Then the lookup would only go through the last record of each user.